# How to convert PHP string in form of array to an actual array

Tags: php, arrays, string, casting, associative-array

I have a PHP string which holds following:

```
array(

    '329' => array(
        'primary' => 'CIVICRM_QFID_394_', //hide this
        'additional' => 'CIVICRM_QFID_398_', //hide this
        'price_options_radio_name' => 'price_188'
    ),
    '336' => array(
        'primary' => 'CIVICRM_QFID_429_', //hide this
        'additional' => 'CIVICRM_QFID_430_', //hide this
        'price_options_radio_name' => 'price_211'
    ),
    '348' => array(
        'primary' => 'CIVICRM_QFID_394_', //hide this
        'additional' => 'CIVICRM_QFID_398_', //hide this
        'price_options_radio_name' => 'price_188'
    ),
);
```

how can this string be converted to PHP array with same structure as in string? I have tried typecasting and unserialize but that did not help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no nice way to turn a string of PHP code into a PHP data structure. There's `eval()` but it's not nice. My advice would be to alter whatever creates the string to create something better via `json_encode()` or `serialize()`

Comment: eval() worked for me, just needed to add "return" before array start. Thanks @phil